# express subdomain routing issue

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain

I am using the `express-subdomain` module for my website but when I use this code :

```
const express = require('express')
const subdomain = require('express-subdomain')
const app = express()

const apiRouter = express.Router()
apiRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to the API!")
})

app.use(subdomain('api', apiRouter))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Main domain - Homepage")
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Main domain - About")
})
```

I get the following results :

- `website.com` -> shows the main index page as expected
- `website.com/about` -> shows the 'about' page as expected
- `api.website.com` -> shows index page of API subdomain as expected
- `api.website.com/about` -> shows 'about' page of the main domain `website.com` !!! <--- not good

So the routes of the primary domain are also being applied for the subdomains. 
I have sought through Google, but nothing found :(

Any help on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each subdomain, you need to handle a 404 error separately:

```
const express = require('express')
const subdomain = require('express-subdomain')
const app = express()
const apiRouter = express.Router()

apiRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to the API!")
})

apiRouter.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404)
  next(new Error('Not found'))
})

app.use(subdomain('api', apiRouter))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Main domain - Homepage")
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Main domain - About")
})
```